# Question about a chessboard's material

Tags: chessboards, identify-this

https://kingchesssets.com/products/black-anigre-wooden-chess-board-24-inches

I found this chess board made of a certain type of wood. What exactly is Black Anigre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so what is black anigre?

If you take the trouble to read what it says at the link you gave then you get this answer:

> The chess board is made of Black Anigre. Anigre is an African hardwood commonly used for plywood, interior furniture, cabinetry, and high-end millwork applications.